# Design of a database for personal inventory

Tags: database-design

I have a table with the users. Each user has a field max. I have another table products. Each user is allowed specific quantities of products according to their field max. I need a way to keep track of their orders so they don't buy more.

Example: User A has max = 1000. He buys 100 + 200 + 300. Next time the system should not allow an order over 400.

Any ideas how to design this?

Comment: MySQL. Why is that important?

Comment: syntax, functions available, etc

Answer (score 2):

In the "users" table, have another field that is a counter of how many items they have ordered (e.g. "items_ordered_count").

When they are shopping, the max number of items they can add to cart is users.max minus users.items_ordered_count.

When they checkout, increase items_ordered_count by number of items ordered.